# Copying multiple files in gnuroot debian

Tags: gnuroot

I was running GNURoot Debian on my android to get a debian environment (as I am a student and can't afford a PC). I have some image files in a directory and want to copy them all at the same time so I typed the following command

```
$ cp -v *.png destination
```

But I got the following error

```
cp: cannot stat '*.png' : No such file or directory
```

I understood the error but I can't understand why this happens.

I will be glad if someone can answer me and provide me with an alternate method or solution.

Comment: edit your question with the output of **ls** with the directory which *.png files recide.

Answer (score 0):

This error is being thrown when there are no files matching the wildcard.
Please check if you can see and access these files with ls.
In case you cannot, modifying their permission to be accessible should solve the problem.